# When iptables is started, there is no ftp access because of timeout

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, ftp

When I start the iptables service, there is no ftp access because of a connection timeout. When I stop the iptables service, ftp works fine.

This is the current iptables data:

**Update**: replaced ESTABLISHED for NEW in p21 rule. The problem is [still happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoQmf.png).

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.7 on Sun Dec 14 23:48:26 2014
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4:2848]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG NONE -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j DROP 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG FIN,SYN,RST,PSH,ACK,URG -j DROP 
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
# Completed on Sun Dec 14 23:48:26 2014
```

Could any of these lines causing this strange behavior?

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 20 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024:65535 --dport 1024:65535 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -
```

I've tried connecting to the ftp server in both passive and active modes.

Comment: Is this box an ftp **client** or ftp **server**.  It isn't clear from your question?  If it is a server then look closer at your rules.  An **incoming** connection will be **new**.

Comment: @Zoredache just tried that. Update ESTABLISHED for NEW, but it is still [timing out](http://i.imgur.com/JTmBBmA.png) when trying to connect with an ftp client.

Comment: check my answer on configuring iptables for ftp. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10400672/linux-bash-setting-iptables-rules-to-allow-both-active-and-passive-ftp/27362948#27362948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically where you have

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

On a FTP server I would expect

```
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
```

to accept incoming FTP connections, which are NEW, as existing connections are already accepted by an earlier rule.

Second you'll need to ensure the FTP connection tracking module is enabled. Offhand : `insmod nf_conntrack_ftp` and made persistent by:

```
# /etc/sysconfig/iptables-config 
# Space separated list of nat helpers (e.g. 'ip_nat_ftp ip_nat_irc'), which
# are loaded after the firewall rules are applied. Options for the helpers are
# stored in /etc/modprobe.conf.
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp"
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that in a moment. Quick question, what's the difference with that and nf_conntrack_netbios? (that's what im using right now)

Comment: netbios is a different protocol from FTP and they each have their own helper module.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the delay, just tested your  recommendation, still this is the [ftp client response](http://i.imgur.com/JTmBBmA.png): Connection timed out - any ideas?

Comment: it seems it was an order issue. I moved the 21 port rule before the 80 port rule and it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: When you changed the configuration the first time (i.e., `--sport 21` to `--dport 21`), did you remember to reload the iptables rules?

Comment: @pepoluan of course!